# Injective compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, compact-operators

The typical example of a compact, injective operator on $\ell^2$ is
$$ K = \text{diag}(1,1/2,1/3,...).$$

I'm struggeling to understand why this operator has $\text{ker}(K) = \{0\}$ (which it should given it the injectivity), since for the unit vector basis $ \{e_n\}$ with $e_n = (0,0,...,1,0,...)$
we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} Ke_n = \lim 1/n = 0,$$
but $\|e_n\| = 1$.

What am I missing here? Is the limit element not a proper element of $\ell^2$, or is it because the sequence $\{e_n\}$ is not convergent?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you really asking "why this operator does *not* ker(K)≠{0}" i.e. "why ker(K)={0}"? And what is the relationship of that question with $\lim Ke_n=0$?

Answer (score 1):

$\forall x:=(x_n)\in\ell^2\quad(Kx)=(x_n/n)$ is the $0$-sequence iff all $x_n$'s are $0,$ i.e. iff $x=0.$ Hence $\ker K=\{0\}.$